# How to insert HTML code to a div without running it

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert html code to a div using javascript, when i am doing this then my html code is running i just want html code not output.

```js
document.getElementById("htmlcode").innerHTML = `<button>Click me</button>`
```

```html
<span id="htmlcode">HTML code here</span>
```

my output:-
[image]
desired output something like this:-
[image: something like this but i need Click me]

Comment: If you want the code to show, consider [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (and probably safest) way is to use [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode).

```js
document.getElementById("htmlcode")
  .replaceChildren(document.createTextNode(`<button>Click me</button>`))
```

```html
<span id="htmlcode">HTML code here</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may replace each:

```
 & with &amp; 
 < with &lt;
 > with &gt;
```

And you should surround the resulting, escaped HTML code within `<pre><code>…</code></pre>` to:

1. preserve whitespace and line breaks, and
2. mark it up as a code element.

In your case:

```
document.getElementById("htmlcode").innerHTML = "<pre><code>&lt;button>Click me&lt;/button</code></pre>"
```